# How to extract from bootstrap the only css properties we need for our project

Tags: css, node.js, twitter-bootstrap

I am currently working on node js and I have a question.
I would like to know if there is a way to extract only the CSS properties needed in our project so as not to have a CSS file too bulky?
I don't know if I make myself understood so I'll be more precise.

I need to use only the btn, btn-default bootstrap properties in my project.
Except that using Bootstrap CDN, this is a large file that will only be used for two properties.

Is there a way or tool that can solve my problem?

I look forward to hearing from you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible to add bootstrap as your dependency via [npm](https://www.npmjs.com/package/bootstrap) (package manager):

```
$ npm install bootstrap@4.0.0-beta
```

All source files will be downloaded into `node_modules/bootstrap` directory. Afterwards you can include only those components you need in your SASS file, like:

```
@import 'path/to/node_modules/bootstrap/scss/_buttons.scss';
```

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you can. In Bootstrap 3.3 and above, you can customize your bootstrap file according to your need.
Go to the link for more information.
https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/customize/
If you still not getting. Let me know.[Dimitri K. Sifoua](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8248523/dimitri-k-sifoua)
[image: Like below]

Answer (score 1):

As pointed out by @Vikash.777 you can customize your bootstrap to your liking, this includes colors and measures but also the different features of bootstrap that you want to be included or not.

Another way could be to simply open the bootstrap CSS and extract all you want from it... This way you'd make sure that you have only the parts you want.

Note that the bootstrap CDN delivers the full version, and even if you do not use everything, other websites also use this CDN and might very well mean that your visitor already has it in its cache. That would mean they won't have to download anything unless you modified it.